# A tool to transfer files using SSH in the browser on GCP it's doesn't work for run PHP files

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I use a tool to transfer files using SSH in the browser on GCP
 (centos7, Apache 2.4.6, php7.3) that copies PHP files 
from Windows PC to /var/www/html. When I do this I cannot run my website.
But when I use the command cp to copy those files 
I can run the website. Who recognizes this problem, please and can help me?

Comment: As a first glance, I would say that the permissions are not correctly inherited while transferring then through SSH. Could you please check if the permissions are correctly set in your GCE Instnace with [chmod](https://www.howtogeek.com/437958/how-to-use-the-chmod-command-on-linux/) ?

Comment: Review the PHP error log file for error messages. This will tell you what is wrong. File permissions are one possibility but file end-of-line (unix versus windows) can be another.

Comment: Another possible problem is the wrong `owner` or `group`. Compare the file permissions, owner, group and EOL (end-of-line) format between a file that works and does not work. Your web files should be owned by the same user as the Apache process.

Comment: I've check permissions with sudo chmod and chown 
 and  No php error log file. Thank you everyone.